# Setting Datagridview cell Value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to assign a double value to one of the cell in datagridview, its not happening. could you please help me resolving this. Below is the simple code which i am using.

```
    minValue = Common.Instance.LstSignalData[nCnt].DictSignalPlotData.Values.Min();
    dataGridView_Head.Rows[nIndex].Cells["Min"].Value = (double)minValue;
```

Comment: what error exception?

Comment: There is no error or exception. datagridview is not getting updated with the assigned value.

Comment: try to dataGridView_Head.Refresh(); after you put the `minValue` to that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
minValue = Common.Instance.LstSignalData[nCnt].DictSignalPlotData.Values.Min();
dataGridView_Head.Rows[nIndex].Cells["Min"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(minValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

`Convert.ToDouble(minValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the index in Cells collection.

`minValue = Common.Instance.LstSignalData[nCnt].DictSignalPlotData.Values.Min();
 dataGridView_Head.Rows[nIndex].Cells[nCellIndex].Value = (double)minValue;`

Comment: No Indexing not helping!!